# Is there a way to PlaySound (PlaySoundA c++ function) only when bool is set to true?

Tags: c++, variables, boolean, playsound

```
PlaySoundA(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Rall0ck\\Downloads\\rabbit.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP | SND_FILENAME );
```

So there is global bool set to false, when I hold R on my keyboard it should play sound (it sets bool to true) but it doesn't, result is : Sound starts, sound stops and repeats… instead of just playing it till end.. (till I stop holding R)

Any solutions?? Thanks.

Comment: You're probably calling `PlaySound` repeatedly.  Run your program under a debugger to check.

Comment: its in inf loop